# How to get dictionary item based on an object with the same hashcode?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashcode

Consider the following private member:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<CollectionInfo, ServiceInfo> _collectionsServicesMapping;
```

The class `CollectionInfo` overrides and adds some additional properties:

```
class CollectionInfo
{
    public Guid InstanceId { get; set; }

    public string CollectionName { get; set; }

    public string WorkFlowName { get; set; }

    public Guid DomainId { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is CollectionInfo && (obj as CollectionInfo).InstanceId.Equals(InstanceId);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return InstanceId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

In the context that I need, I'm looking for `CollectionInfo` by InstanceId:

```
private IRequestHandler GetServiceByInstanceId(Guid instanceId)
{
}
```

Two optional solutions that I see:

```
_collectionsServicesMapping.TryGetValue(new CollectionInfo() { InstanceId = instanceId }, out si)

_collectionsServicesMapping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.InstanceId.Equals(instanceId));
```

But this force me either **create a redundant fake instance** of the class `CollectionInfo` or **to scan all the dictionary**.

Is there a way to get a dictionary item, based on an object that has the same hashcode in another more efficient way?

Comment: Why not `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ServiceInfo>` instead? No nead to have `CollectionInfo` as the key.

Comment: Why is the dictionary mapping from collection infos in the first place, if it is actually mapping on their ids?  Just make a map from ids.

Comment: This is a viable option, and what I started with. I need to use both `CollectionInfo` and `ServiceInfo` in this context. Just wondered if there is a way to save additional dictionary and managing concurrency between them.

Comment: I think you need to review all the use cases you have for the collection(s)  (including how it will be updated as well as queried) to determine the most appropriate structure. There are a lot of possibilities, and you might be best served by creating a collection class of your own that simplifies the interface and allows you to change the underlying implementation without breaking the code that uses it.

Comment: I agree with @JackA. But doesn't FirstOrDefault exits when first occurrence is found, thus preventing from a full scan ?

Comment: @xum59 - This is O(n) operation on the average case, which is very expansive for getting an item from data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a dictionary item, based on an object that has the same hashcode in **another more efficient way**?

Unfortunately no. Contrary to the Philip Pittle's answer, I think you (and anyone else in the similar situation) **do** have a problem. We are victims of what I would call **too much encapsulation**, started with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and followed by the `ConcurentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Both classes could easily expose a method like

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetItems(int hashCode)
```

or

```
bool TryGetValue(int hashCode, Func<TKey, bool> predicate, out TValue value)
```

but they don't. Unfortunately something similar cannot be simulated outside the class implementation.

So you are stuck with the **workarounds** mentioned. I would pick the **fake instance** approach - at least you can, sometimes there is no such luxury (if the class requires complex constructor with strong validation not allowing fake instantiation). And wait for MS to open source the BCL :-)

P.S. What about creating a different dictionary by `Guid`, why should one keep 2 copies of a `Guid` (16 bytes value type) if it's already contained in a instance of a class?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really have a problem here.  But let's walk through it (see the end for what I'd recommend).

> Create a redundant fake instance

Creating a new instance is a relatively inexpensive operation.  Is the code a bit uglier then using the Guid directly, sure.  But if that's your concern, you have plenty of options:

```
//excention method (in some static class)
public static ServiceInfo GetServiceByGuid (
   this ConcurrentDictionary<CollectionInfo, ServiceInfo> dic, Guid id){
   ServiceInfo si;
   dic.TryGetValue(new CollectionInfo() { InstanceId = id}, out si);
   return si;
}
```

or

```
//implicit coversion operator (in CollectionInfo)
public static implicit operator CollectionInfo(Guid id){
    return new CollectionInfo(new CollectionInfo() { InstanceId = id};
}
```

then you can just pass the Guid `instanceId` to the dictionary's `TryGetValue` method.

> Scan all the dictionary

There's no reason to take this approach.  You're technically scanning only the keys and not the "entire" dictionary, but `TryGetValue` will be more performant as it can leverage hashing to quickly find the Item you're looking for.

> Change the dictionary

So after that, this is what I think you want:

`ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Tuple<CollectionInfo, ServiceInfo>>`

This way you still get concurrency, you can match `CollectionInfo`/`ServiceInfo` based on a guid (id), and you don't have to mess with overloads (`GetHashCode()` in `CollectionInfo`).

```
private IRequestHandler GetServiceByInstanceId(Guid instanceId)
{
   Tuple<CollectionInfo,ServiceInfo> pair;
   if (_collectionsServicesMapping.TryGetValue(instanceId, out pair))
   {
      return pair.Item2;
   }

   // whatever you want to return if instanceId wasn't found
   return null;
}
```

Comment: I think the last part of your answer is what should be highlighted.  `InstanceId` should be the key, and `CollectionInfo` + `ServiceInfo` need to be combined into the value.